# How to get autocomplete feature for SwiftVapor in Ubuntu VSCode

Tags: swift, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vapor

I'm using Vapor in Ubuntu through VSCode but the problem is i'm getting autocomplete only for Swift through Swift extension but it does not work for Vapor.Is there is any autocomplete extension available for VS Code to get auto complete feature while worlking with Vapor.

Comment: Autocomplete either work or not at all. It not depends on Vapor. Now you don’t have real SourceKit autocomplete at all. What you have is just suggestions not connected to compiler.

Comment: Oh then there is not way to add it.Is autocomplete work with Xcode???

Comment: Have you tried to setup sourcekit-lsp somehow like described here? https://medium.com/@pvzig/swift-development-with-visual-studio-code-on-linux-99cac3918582

Comment: There are a number of other tutorials as well, e.g. [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/vscode/) and [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8325890-a-complete-guide-to-swift-development-on-linux)